# iPhone MapKit: use bike layer?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview

Google maps API provides an option to show a bicycle layer. Is this also possible with MapKit?

Answer (score 0):

Neither driving nor bicycle directions are "natively" supported in MapKit. There are numerous other questions here that cover how to construct overlays for directions by leveraging Google's map apis. I'd start there but you'll have to roll your own solution using MapKits overlay capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, **no**.

A lot of Google Map API features are missing from the MapKit framework, and with the latest drama between Google and Apple, it would seem that Apple is looking beyond Google to provide their mapservices.